# An abstract class method generic to all children

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, c++20

I am designing a structure which employs inheritance. The parent class is abstract and basically have two methods. One is pure virtual, the other one, I am not so sure what should I do with it. It's just a function that starts a thread with the pure virtual one, and it will be generic to all the children, but I don't know if it's possible.

```
struct Parent{

    std::thread th;

    void watch(){
        th = std::thread(&______::do_watch, this); 
    };

    virtual void do_watch() = 0;
};

struct Child1 : Parent{
    void do_watch();
};

struct Child2 : Parent{
    void do_watch();
};

struct Child3 : Parent{
    void do_watch();
};
```

As you can see, the method `watch` will actually be the same across all children, but the parent doesn't know the children so something like `Child::do_watch` is impossible. Do I really have to make this function virtual as well, and just copy it to all child classes ?

Or is there a way to share this function with all child classes, without having to rewrite them in the children (because it's going to call `do_watch` anyway, which is pure virtual and guaranteed to exist).

**Edit_1:**

```
th = std::thread([this](){this->do_watch();});
```

This seems to compile, without having to give the name of the class. But I don't know if it would cause an undefined behavior.

Comment: Why not provide a generic implementation in `Parent` if specialization isn't needed?

Comment: @StephenNewell It's needed in other aspects which is irrelevant for the question (If you mean combining all the classes to the Parent.)

Comment: Then write a common function the children call from their `do_watch`.

Comment: @StephenNewell Can you elaborate ? You mean adding the `watch` method to all children ?

Comment: What are you hoping to gain from inheritance? Could it be achieved by defining a concept detailing the need for a specific set of functions required?

Comment: @MikelF All the children will have very different `do_watch` methods, very different constructors. But they also share a lot of variables with the parent, which I didn't include to the question. The design is %100 OOP(basically `Animal` parent and `Rabbit`, `Eagle` as children), I just added the necessary parts to the question.

Comment: @Rockybilly When you say the `do_watch` methods are different, do you mean different function signatures, or different contents?

Comment: You just write `&Parent::do_watch`. No, there is no problem. Yes, it does what you want.

Comment: @MikelF different contents. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to virtualize it. Mentioned that just to emphasize one of the benefits of me using inheritance, since you asked.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That works if I have to define `watch` in all child classes, which I was trying to find out if avoidable. The lambda solution seems like it's gonna work, I am checking.

Comment: `std::thread(&Parent::do_watch, this)` works exactly the same and does exactly the same thing as `std::thread([this](){this->do_watch();})`. Why do you think you need to define `watch` more than once in one case and not in the other?

Comment: Why do you think there's an issue with `n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.`'s approach? It's working fine: https://godbolt.org/z/7vPqMdTbK

Comment: @fabian Thank you for your effort. Please check my previous comment.

Comment: That's inheritance 101: When calling a virtual function (pure virtual or not) on a reference to a class the version of the function closest to the real type of the object in the inheritance hierarchy. Your question is basically equivalent to asking why `Child3 c3; Parent& asParent = c3; asParent.do_work();` calls `Child3::do_work`. The reason for my downvote is the fact that you simply claim the solution obvious to a programmer that understands inheritance does not work, but being wrong without indicating where the misconception comes from.Me taking back the downvote is unlikely even with edit

Comment: @fabian That's totally fine as long as I know the reason :) I am here to learn, and to demolish my false assumptions on the language(one goal accomplished). Nevertheless, as to your example, it's pretty natural for me, but was not so obvious for me when defining the function itself like `Parent::`. Even though I use equivalent code like `((Parent*)child)->func`. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This is indeed a bit confusing. When you call `Parent::do_watch()` directly, this function is called without virtual dispatch mechanism. But when you take a function address, the virtual dispatch mechanism is not suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might help you refresh your mind to the idea of Inheritance and pure virtual Function, and for the Benefit of Others ( Like Me which was thrown for a Quadruple loop on Inheritance).

By making `do_watch()` a pure virtual function you are specifically saying to the compiler "This Code is not defined in this Struct/Class, every Child of this struct/class will have it's own definition."

If you need a function to do one thing AND one thing only for every child, you only need to define it in the parent. You don't even need it to be a virtual function since you won't be changing the method in any of the child.

Take the following structs as an example.

```
struct Teacher
{
  int nStudent;
  Teacher():nStudent(20){}
  int GetStudentNumber(){return nStudent;}
  virtual int IncrementStudent ( ){ nStudent++ ; return nStudent;};
  virtual void RemoveStudent()=0;
  virtual void AddStudent() {nStudent++;};
  void ParentRemove(){RemoveStudent();};
};
struct WeirdTeacher :public Teacher
{
  void AddStudent(){nStudent+=10;}
  void RemoveStudent(){nStudent-=10;}
};
struct SuperWeirdTeacher :public Teacher
{
  void AddStudent(){nStudent-=1;}
  int IncrementStudent(){nStudent+=2;return nStudent;}
  void RemoveStudent(){nStudent+=nStudent;}
};
struct PseudoTeacher:public Teacher
{
private:
    int nKidnappedStudent;
public:
    void RemoveStudent(){
        nKidnappedStudent = nStudent;
        nStudent-=nStudent;
    };
    int GetKidnappedStudent(){return nKidnappedStudent;};
/* The code won't compile if you remove this
and remind you that the parent is an Abstract since it has at least one
pure virtual function  */
};
```

Each of the Child Struct is Required to define `RemoveStudent()`

Each child struct will implement their own definition of `RemoveStudent()` when they call `ParentRemove()` and MUST HAVE a definition of it even if that Child will not use `ParentRemove()`.While `IncrementStudent()` , A Virtual Function, defined in the Parent will get called if it is not defined in the Children Class , else it calls the Child's definition of the function.
e.g.

```
int main()
{
 SuperWeirdTeacher swt;
 WeirdTeacher wt;
 PseudoTeacher pt;
 swt.AddStudent();//Calls Child Definition
 wt.AddStudent();//Calls Child Definition
 pt.AddStudent();//Calls Parent Definition
 // Calls Parent Definition
 std::cout<<"Weird Teacher Has ["<<wt.IncrementStudent()<<"] Students"<<std::endl;
 // Calls Child Definition
 std::cout<<"Super Weird Teacher Has ["<<swt.IncrementStudent()<<"] Students"<<std::endl;
 // Calls Parent Definition
 std::cout<<"Pseudo Teacher Has ["<<pt.GetStudentNumber()<<"] Students"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
 swt.ParentRemove(); // Calls Child Definition of RemoveStudent()
 wt.ParentRemove(); // Calls Child Definition of RemoveStudent()
 pt.ParentRemove(); // Calls Child Definition of RemoveStudent()
 std::cout<<"Weird Teacher Has ["<<wt.GetStudentNumber()<<"] Students"<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"Super Weird Teacher Has ["<<swt.GetStudentNumber()<<"] Students"<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"Pseudo Teacher Has ["<<pt.GetStudentNumber()<<"] Students"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"Pseudo Teacher Has Kidnapped["<<pt.GetKidnappedStudent()<<"] Students"<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Weird Teacher Has [31] Students
Super Weird Teacher Has [21] Students
Pseudo Teacher Has [21] Students

Weird Teacher Has [21] Students
Super Weird Teacher Has [42] Students
Pseudo Teacher Has [0] Students

Pseudo Teacher Has Kidnapped [21] Students
```

The Whole point of a pure virtual Function is to tell the compiler that the Function's Definition can be Found not on this Parent but on a child and use it anytime the function is called. That is why `th = std::thread([this](){this->do_watch();});` works,since when `watch()` is called from a Child, it would refer to the child's definition of `do_watch()` even if The Parent has no Idea what `do_watch()` will do for the Child Class(Refer to PseudoTeacher).

P.S. To Lazy to Change the idea of the structs mid-posting, so Forgive me for the Dark twist, And the Sample is to show how Crazy you can get with Inheritance, But don't get to crazy :)
P.P.S Don't Take our words as gospel, we only tell what we have experienced.